# maven m2e proxy connection issues with PAC, in Eclipse; How to Debug?

Tags: maven, maven-3, m2e

I got the Eclipse EE and realized it did not have maven/m2e, so I got m2e installed.
Then I am setting up projects and using pom.xml I start getting all the fun errors like:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin....,
*_*_ or one of it's dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ....,
Failure to transfer .....

Since I'm in a corporate environment, I find the IE setting and go find the PAC ( proxy auto-configuration ) script. 
Then I enter those values into a  in my settings.xml   area.
I even tried some of the ideas shared by developers, such as deleting .lastupdated files and deleting directories.
Even though it totally defeats the whole idea of maven, I'm considering transfering all my .jar & .pom files from another machine's repository.

No joy yet.  Something is still wrong, I just don't know what yet. 
I seriously need some debugging or logging or a ping test, if there is anything available to discover what the problem is.

I found some great posts on Maven and Proxy.  keywords: maven, m2e,  'failed to transfer', pom.xml, settings, proxy, etc.
also 
Cannot download maven dependencies through proxy
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5237
   after reading this, and not knowing if my company was using NTLM, I put in the wagon lightweight jar and referred to it with  in pom.xml
  How will I know, If I do end up needing this ??  and 
  where should I put the .jar file ?  in the user repository area, or deep in the maven runtime \jars\ directory ?

Along the way, some questions also came up.
( for reference, I am on WinXP )

With an m2e only, do I need a $M2_HOME defined ?  I'm thinking not, since I don't know where that would be.
related:  With m2e, will I ever have a global settings.xml  ?

Should the  ${user.home}.m2/repository  be referenced (and uncommented) in the local settings.xml    ?

As a substitute for the command line maven, can Eclise 'Run Configurations' really be a full replacement ?
  I know the dialog box you use, has the empty list of goals, when it should be populated, but you can always type in 
  What about using  'mvn -X' 
  Or any of the other cool maven commands, like the one that shows you all the transitive dependencies.

Still searching, but Thanks In Advance for anyone who can assist in resolving these Proxy issues.

Comment: Playing around with different proxies (supplied in the PAC) I have been more successful, getting m2e to retrieve the jar sha1 and properties files, but still not getting the .pom for this dependency, and even if I copy the file there manually, the build issue does not go away.  Error: Could not calculate build plan:  AND  Failed to read artifact descriptor

Comment: If there really is a block, transfer or security issue, I'd be tempted to set up a local repository.